# Workflow for User Secrets in .netcore?

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm playing around in .netcore and attempting to make use of the user secret store, some details are here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html

I'm getting along with it well enough when working locally, but I'm having trouble understanding how this could be utilized effectively in a team environment, and if I wanted to work on this project from more than one computer.

The store itself (at least by default) keeps its configuration json file within the users/appdata (on windows).  This feature is good to use if you're uploading the project to github, to hide your API keys, connection strings etc.  This is all great when it's just me, on one machine working on a project.  But how does this work when working in a team environment, or on multiple machines?  The only thing I can think of is to find the configuration file, check it into a private repo, and make sure to replace it in the correct directory when changes occur.

Is there another way to manage this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Maybe evaluate your companies policies? If your working computer is connected via domain, then the profiles will be synched anyways accross computers, since it's stored in AppData\Remote\Microsoft\UserSecrets folder

Comment: Hey @Tseng thanks, but I'm less concerned about myself connected to a domain.  I'm more concerned about myself working on different machines in my house (are microsoft profile informations shared in the appdata?) and different developers in an organization.  What are my options in these scenarios?

Comment: You can also use environment variables instead of secrets, both options are scriptable and are pretty simple to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already know, the Secret Manager tool is providing another method to avoid checking sensitive data into source control by adding this layer of control.

So, where should we store sensitive configuration instead?  The location should obviously be separate from your source code and, more importantly, secure. It could be in a separate private repository, protected fileshare, document management system, etc.

Rather than finding and sharing the exact configuration file, however, I would suggest keeping a script (e.g. .bat file) that you would run on each machine to set your secrets.  For example:

```
dotnet user-secrets set MySecret1 ValueOfMySecret1 --project c:\work\WebApp1
dotnet user-secrets set MySecret2 ValueOfMySecret2 --project c:\work\WebApp1
```

This would be more portable between machines and avoid the hassle of knowing where to find and copy the config files themselves.

Also, for these settings, consider whether you need them to be the same across all developers in your team.  For local development, I would normally want to have control to install, use, and name resources differently than others in my team.  Of course, this depends on your situation and preferences, and I see reasons to share them too.

Comment: thanks, I couldn't get the `--project...` to work, but i just threw a CD [dir] as the first statement in the batch file.

Comment: makes sense.  i suppose that path would be user-specific anyway, so just doing the change directory in the script is just as good.  glad it helped.